# Access value of selected option in <select> element with PHP

Tags: php, html, combobox

I am trying to create a simple form that will send data to a PHP script upon submitting the form. I am able to access all of the textbox values, and have successfully implemented variables for each of them. However, when I try to access the value of a combo box on my form, I get this error in the PHP:

> Notice: Undefined index: cmbProvince in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\krAssignment4\scripts\index.php on line 15

HTML

```
<form id="orderForm" action="scripts/index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <fieldset id="customerInfo">
            <legend>Customer Information</legend>

            <label for="txtFirstName">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName"
                   placeholder="First Name" autofocus="true"
                   oninput="formatFirstName()">
            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName"
                   placeholder="Last Name" oninput="formatLastName()"><br><br>

            <label for="txtAddress">Address:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" placeholder="Address"
                   oninput="formatAddress()"><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" placeholder="City"
                   oninput="formatCity()">
            <select id="cmbProvince" name="cmbProvince">
                <option value="on">ON</option>
                <option value="qc">QC</option>
                <option value="mb">MB</option>
                <option value="sk">SK</option>
                <option value="ab">AB</option>
                <option value="bc">BC</option>
                <option value="nb">NB</option>
                <option value="nl">NL</option>
                <option value="ns">NS</option>
                <option value="nu">NU</option>
                <option value="pe">PE</option>
                <option value="nt">NT</option>
                <option value="yt">YT</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtPostalCode" name="txtPostalCode"
                   placeholder="Postal Code" oninput="displayPostalCode()">
            <br><br>
            <!-- Button that will display the order form -->
            <input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Order"
                   onclick="showOrderInformation()">
        </fieldset><br>

        <fieldset id="orderInfo">
            <legend>Order Information</legend>

            <label for="cmbProduct">Product:</label><br>
            <select id="cmbProduct">
                <option> -- Select -- </option>
                <option>Blackberries</option>
            </select>
            &ensp;@&ensp;
            <input type="number" id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" value="1"
                   step="1" min="1" max="50" oninput="displayTotalTax()"><br><br>
        </fieldset>
        <br><br>

        <!-- Button to submit the form to PHP after validation -->
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

PHP (lines 10 - 19)

```
/* Capture the user input from the HTML form */
$strFirstName = $_POST['txtFirstName'];
$strLastName = $_POST['txtLastName'];
$strAddress = $_POST['txtAddress'];
$strCity = $_POST['txtCity'];
$strProvince = $_POST['cmbProvince'];
$strPostalCode = $_POST['txtPostalCode'];
```

Am I typing something wrong? Or missing something? Everything **except** the combo box is working.

Let me know if I need to include anything else. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Here is what happens when I try `var_dump($_POST);`:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cmbProvince in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\krAssignment4\scripts\index.php on line 15 
Notice: Undefined index: cmbProduct in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\krAssignment4\scripts\index.php on line 18 
array(6) { ["txtFirstName"]=> string(7) "Kendall" 
["txtLastName"]=> string(4) "Roth" 
["txtAddress"]=> string(19) "22 Resolution Drive" 
["txtCity"]=> string(8) "Millbank" 
["txtPostalCode"]=> string(7) "K2K 2K2" 
["txtQuantity"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get comobox value in `scripts/index.php` file??

Comment: This isn't the full form code. Is it possible to show the full code? There might be something in it that's preventing the select from going to the server

Comment: does the error happen when you don't select any option? if so, you have to include a pre-selected option in your select, `<option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>`

Comment: Make sure you validating $_POST with `isset($_POST)`.

Comment: @disf.asia No, I already tried that. Same problem.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and share the results#

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer That is correct

Comment: try to check what is being sent from your browser using network tab in your browser console

Comment: use double quote instead of single quote $_POST["cmbProvince"];

Comment: @RajnikantSharma Unfortunately, that also does nothing different

Comment: I am getting all the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me with a little bit changes, try this:

```
    <form id="orderForm" action="scripts/index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <fieldset id="customerInfo">
                <legend>Customer Information</legend>

                <label for="txtFirstName">Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName"
                       placeholder="First Name" autofocus="true"
                       oninput="formatFirstName()">
                <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName"
                       placeholder="Last Name" oninput="formatLastName()"><br><br>

                <label for="txtAddress">Address:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" placeholder="Address"
                       oninput="formatAddress()"><br>
                <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" placeholder="City"
                       oninput="formatCity()">
                <select id="cmbProvince" name="cmbProvince">
                    <option value="on">ON</option>
                    <option value="qc">QC</option>
                    <option value="mb">MB</option>
                    <option value="sk">SK</option>
                    <option value="ab">AB</option>
                    <option value="bc">BC</option>
                    <option value="nb">NB</option>
                    <option value="nl">NL</option>
                    <option value="ns">NS</option>
                    <option value="nu">NU</option>
                    <option value="pe">PE</option>
                    <option value="nt">NT</option>
                    <option value="yt">YT</option>
                </select><br>
                <input type="text" id="txtPostalCode" name="txtPostalCode"
                       placeholder="Postal Code" oninput="displayPostalCode()">
                <br><br>
                <!-- Button that will display the order form -->
                <input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Order"
                       onclick="showOrderInformation()">
            </fieldset><br>

            <fieldset id="orderInfo">
                <legend>Order Information</legend>

                <label for="cmbProduct">Product:</label><br>
             <select id="cmbProduct" name="cmbProduct"> //changes is in this code   
                    <option> -- Select -- </option>
                    <option value="Blackberries">Blackberries</option>
                </select>
                &ensp;@&ensp;
                <input type="number" id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" value="1"
                       step="1" min="1" max="50" oninput="displayTotalTax()"><br><br>
            </fieldset>
            <br><br>

            <!-- Button to submit the form to PHP after validation -->
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

In your index.php write:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);die;
}
?>
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [txtFirstName] => a
    [txtLastName] => b
    [txtAddress] => c
    [txtCity] => d
    [cmbProvince] => qc
    [txtPostalCode] => e
    [cmbProduct] => Blackberries
    [txtQuantity] => 1
)
```

Comment: not really a useful answer if you don't specify what changes you've made

Comment: I mentioned it with //changes is in this code.Please see in my code

Comment: Thanks! From your code I realize that I forgot to add a `value` for the Product combo box! Also, does PHP require the `name` attribute of an element instead of the `id`?

Comment: However, I am not sure what changed for the first combo box, as I did absolutely nothing to affect it, but it still works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KendallRoth  you are right. name attribute is taken rather than id. And if this answer is helpful then marked it.It helps other to find out solution.Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Kendall, you were:

- missing name for your `<select id="cmbProduct">`, and
- missing value for your `cmbProduct` options as well

Putting in 'disabled selected' is a good practice as well as people won't be able to select the 'select' option :)

Your code

```
<select id="cmbProduct">
   <option> -- Select -- </option>
   <option>Blackberries</option>
</select>
```

Correct code

```
<select id="cmbProduct" name="cmbProduct>
  <option value="select" disabled selected> -- Select -- </option>
  <option value="blackberries">Blackberries</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The default option doesn't need a value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment schlickenschleider (albeit 5 years after ;) )! I asked something similar in the comments on the marked answer, but this does state it more succinctly.